# Imprimir documento guardado en servidor

Tags: c#, html, sql

estoy creando una pagina web donde los usuarios pueden subir archivos (**exel o word**) y guardarlos en un servidor SQL y que después otros puedan ver esos archivos y que tengan la posibilidad de imprimirlos. La verdad es que estoy teniendo problemas para crear un método que permita imprimir. ¿Hay alguna manera? Gracias.

Tengo todo el código para subir y descargar los archivos por lo que sería un poco tedioso copiar todo el archivo. Para descargar los archivos básicamente uso el método DownloadFromDatabase(File) o para subirlos uso SQL (INSERT...) y despues ExcecuteQuery().

Entonces la pregunta sería simplemente que método/comando existe para imprimir los archivos o explicarme un pequeño ejemplo.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes algo ya hecho? Ayudaría que pusieras código o más contexto y problemática exacta.

Comment: @Kiko_L acabo de editar la pregunta, espero que sea suficiente.

Comment: Me temo que la pregunta sigue siendo demasiado general. Échale un vistazo a esta ayuda de cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Para excel o word 2003+ debes usar Open XML SDK o librerías especiales como devexpress para poderlos "imprimir" sin "descargarlos" (la relialidad es que los descargar pero los imprime sin consultar y quedan en el temp con un nombre raro).

Sin usar librerías del estilo devexpress no vas a poder imprimir en forma directa word o excel ya que al ser archivos de tipos especiales, es el navegador el que decide que se hace con dicho archivo, por ende vas a tener que manipular el archivo como xml y hacer todos los procesos a mano.

[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345309/generate-and-print-a-microsoft-word-document-from-asp-net) hay una respuesta en ingles